# Calling another method when Parallel Testing returns java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, selenium, parallel-processing, testng

I am running into an issue when executing Parallel Tests using Java, Selenium, and TestNG. I have a 2 test methods that search google for two different keywords. I would like a third method that is called by both test methods to avoid repeating similar code.

```
public class googleTestClass extends Methods{

@Test
public void executeGoogle() throws InterruptedException {
    googleTestClass object;
    object = new googleTestClass();
    object.goToURL("https://www.google.com");
    object.enterValue("name","q","google test 1");
}

@Test
public void test1() throws InterruptedException {

    googleTestClass object1;
    object1 = new googleTestClass();
    object1.launchBrowser();
    object1.executeGoogle();
}

@Test
public void test2() throws InterruptedException {

    googleTestClass object2;
    object2 = new googleTestClass();
    object2.launchBrowser();
    object2.executeGoogle();
}
}
```

When my code hits the object1.executeGoogle(); and object2.executeGoogle(); commands, it returns a java.lang.NullPointerException. I have an idea that the error is related to the object but I am not sure how to proceed.

Here are additional classes that are being used.

Method class:

```
// import statements

public class Methods {

public WebDriver driver;

public void launchBrowser() {

     System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.args", "--disable-logging");
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.silentOutput", "true");
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
}

public void goToURL(String url) {
    driver.get(url);
}

    public void enterValue(String htmltype, String identifier, String value) throws InterruptedException {
    if (htmltype == "id") {
        WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id(identifier));
        element.clear();
        element.sendKeys(value);
        element.submit();
    }
    if (htmltype =="name") {
        WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name(identifier));
        element.clear();
        element.sendKeys(value);
        element.submit();
    }

    Thread.sleep(3000);
}
```

}

XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite" parallel="methods">

  <test thread-count="5" name="Test" parallel="methods">
    <classes>
         <class name="webDrivertests.googleTestClass">
            <methods>
                <include name ="test1"/>
                <include name ="test2"/>
            </methods>
        </class>
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are using a method, executeGoogle() which is annotated with @Test, but it is not a test. Remove the annotation

You are trying to instantiate googleTestClass, from within googleTestClass (which should have a capital G, so GoogleTestClass). This seems wrong

You don’t need an instance of googleTestClass to call the methods in Methods class. You can just call them directly since your googleTestClass inherits them

Also Methods is quite a generic name when this class contains methods specific to browser testing. Could you call it BrowserTestBaseFunctions or something similar?

I would also suggest that your executeGoogle() function goes into a Google specific class, which could inherit from the BrowserTestBaseFunctions class... That’s if executeGoogle is actually specific to Google, otherwise you could call it loadUrl and put in BrowserTestBaseFunctions with params to make it more reusable

Comment: Thank you for the advice. Also, this solution worked, thanks!

Comment: if we remove @Test annotation how can running test via XML file ?

Comment: The @Test annotation should only be removed from the executeGoogle() method as it is not a test. The annotation should remain on the actual test methods